# Not Load Footer in the Checkout

Tags: footer

I am running Magento 1.14 EE version. I am also using a third party extension called 'One Step Checkout'
In the checkout, I do not want to load the site footer. 
There is a onestepcheckout.xml which I have edited and added the following lines:

```
<onestepcheckout_index_index>
    <remove name="bottom-footer-new"/>
</onestepcheckout_index_index>
```

I am using the name of 'bottom-footer-new' which is listed in the CMS -> StaticBlocks
It still will not remove the footer.

Comment: Update Your Footer Block here

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles across this from the google compute machine, here is how i fixed the issue.

i was editing the XML in the extensions xml file. I realized my mistake and went to my themes xml file and added this:

```
<onestepcheckout_index_index>
    <remove name="footer"/>
</onestepcheckout_index_index>
```